# Where exactly should I put the call to [FBSettings publishInstall:appId]

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I'm looking at integrating support for tracking Facebook's new mobile app ads.

I've read the tutorial here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/

It says:

> Include the following code to be executed when your app opens for the first time by user
>
> ```
> [FBSettings publishInstall:appId];
> ```

So the first question is - where do I put this so that it only invokes the call if the install was driven from Facebook? I don't want FB to get credit for someone who found my app themselves on the app store.

Do I need to manually track whether or not I've called the publishInstall before for this specific user? (The preamble sentence implies this - but the SDK documentation for publishInstall implies otherwise).

And even more confusing is that the SDK FBSettings reference includes `shouldAutoPublishInstall` which defaults to `YES`. This would suggest that I don't need to do anything other than have the SDK integrated. So why does the tutorial not mention this as an option?

I assume that the appId is the associated Facebook appId (as opposed to the App Store App ID). This is also not clear from the documentation.

Comment: Did you find out any additional information related to this?  I want to use publishInstall to track installs, but don't want to implement any type of Facebook login.  I'm also seeing an issue where on iOS 6+ the Facebook SDK crashes when it goes over the publishInstall line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I browsed the sources of facebook iOS SDK, and it seems that guide is wrong.

You are right, that `autoPublishInstall` is set to `YES` by default, which means we don't need to invoke `[FBSettings publishInstall:appId];` manually. `AppId` is indeed the facebook app id.

When you invoke `openActiveSessionWith....` method, it initializes `FBSession` with
`initWithAppID:permissions:defaultAudience:urlSchemeSuffix:tokenCacheStrategy:` which contains in the end `[FBSettings autoPublishInstall:self.appID];`

```
+ (void)autoPublishInstall:(NSString *)appID {
    if ([FBSettings shouldAutoPublishInstall]) {
        dispatch_once(&g_publishInstallOnceToken, ^{
            // dispatch_once is great, but not re-entrant.  Inside publishInstall we use FBRequest, which will
            // cause this function to get invoked a second time.  By scheduling the work, we can sidestep the problem.
            [[FBSettings class] performSelector:@selector(publishInstall:) withObject:appID afterDelay:FBPublishDelay];
        });
   }
}
```

So technically it should report the install out of the box (if I'm not missing something). I'm going to play with it a little more today to see if it works as expected and update answer with results.

Comment: You are correct, if you implement Facebook Login then publishing should be automatically set up for you. So you don't have to add any code beyond calling the open... methods.

Answer (score 6):

1. Just put it at `-[application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]`.
2. Not all of the apps want to integrate the Facebook login. They only want the feature "mobile  app install ads". For these kind of app, they should invoke `+[FBSettings publishInstall:appId]` manually. On the other hand, if your app has already integrated facebook login, you can assume that the FB sdk has published the installation.

Answer (score 3):

If we just have to put

```
[FBSettings publishInstall:appId];
```

manually in

```
-[application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]
```

how will I identify which install happened from facebook? I don't want FB to get credit for someone who found my app themselves on the app store.

Answer (score 2):

put the code in Appdelegate DidbecomeActive method

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

hope this help :)

Comment: This is according to their documentation: The SDK 3.1 features a method in the FBSettings class called publishInstall: that asynchronously pings an install event to Facebook when it's invoked. Include it in the applicationDidBecomeActive: method of your app delegate like this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.1/